# How to create a arrow above the table view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to design a view that look like some thing like this. I know this a UITableView below the top bar. but how i can create a arrow like shown in attach image.
Any guide will be helpful
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about **"Creating Arrow"** above `UITableView`, it's about **"Showing White Triangle"** in the Image. Also , Changing the Image of `UIButton` is more Simpler.

Change this Image

[image]

with

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be header view of table.
Use this methode

```
      -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
      {
         UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
                               //create your view here. buttons lable image etc.
         return view;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be different ways to implement this but a much easier way is to use this library [SDSegmentedControl](https://github.com/rs/SDSegmentedControl)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Developer I don't know who voted it down but in my opinion, thats the best solution you can get for the thing you trying to implement

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can create  custom header view instead of giving the background view to all the table . add the background image to the header view with array pointing in the opposite direction .

Answer (score 0):

just use an arrow image in `uiimageview`, as it is only above the `uitableview`.

If the arrow will move to other label for ex, series or title, then just change the frame of that arrow imageview(u can also use `uiviewanimations`). This is what I had done when I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be changing the rest of the view depending on what button the arrow is on, you also might want to look into putting your `UITableViewController` [inside of a `UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You won't be able to get the same colorscheme as you have in your screenshot I don't believe, but a lot of the behind-the-scenes work for changing the rest of the view depending on what is selected will be done for you (or will at least be much easier to set up).  Also, Apple seems to tend to grumble about "non-standard interfaces" when you try to make up your own way of doing something that already can be done with the built-in UI framework.